# Where to find rare fish?

Tags: nier-automata

I've got about 70% of the fish found in the game.  At some point you get an email from one of the characters that says a great place to find rare fish is a subterranean lake near where he lives.

I've taken that to be the puddle/waterfall at the bottom of the ravine between the city ruins and the commercial center, at the end away from the elevator.  However while I've caught a number of things there, they have been extremely common fish (killfish) and junk (RPG).

Am I in the right spot, or is there another location for rare fish?  Is there anyway to increase the chances of getting rare fish?

I am playing on PS4 so answers which would require a mod to the game will not work.

Update:  So the ravine just outside the commercial center which I'm asking about above is NOT Emil's home, which is what is referenced in Emil's email.  Just to be clear, and that's why I wasn't finding some of the rare fish.

Comment: Just say you're on PS4 in the question, the tag is unnecessary for this

Comment: What fish do you have? Have you found the oil field or the oasis? There are some unique fish there.

Comment: @Vemonus I'll have to compile the list when I play tonight.  I've gotten a number from the oil pond, including a biological fish coated in oil.  I did fish a little in the oasis, but again got really common fish only.

Comment: @Andy ah okay, well both places have some rare fish. It's all just up to RNG. I'll post a full answer in a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are rare fish in some of the fishing areas that can't be found anywhere else. The specific rare fish that I believe the character was talking about in that email would be the [Twinfish](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Twinfish) and [Bloatfish](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Bloat+Fish), as those can only be found near that character's house.

Other rare fish would be the [Basking Shark](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Basking+Shark) and [Swordfish](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Swordfish) (and their machine lifeform variants) near the Missile site in the Flooded City, the [Coelacanth](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Coelacanth) (and its machine lifeform variant) near the coast in the same area, the [Beetle Fish](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Beetle+Fish) and [Arowana Machine](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Arowana+Machine) in the Oasis, and the [Fur Carp](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Fur+Carp) and [Arapaima](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Arapaima) on the path to the Ravine.

Those fish can only be found in those specific locations and some of them are fish I've never even seen.

For the full list of fish in the game, [here's a link to the wiki](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Fish).

Comment: I've gotten the bloatfish in the river outside the resistance camp actually.  Machine bloatfish somewhere too.

Comment: @Andy ah, the wiki says those are in Underground Cave, so that is somewhere else. The wiki isn't consistent, it seems. However, I definitely have only found Twinfish near that character's house.

Comment: Ya I don't have the twinfish; I thought I did but I had twohead instead.

Comment: I actually found Emil's home now and found the lake; I thought it was the ravine where the Lord of the Valley takes place, but it wasn't, that was my confusion.